# Are there any examples of using gwt for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, gwt

I have a java library which I wish to use in nodejs. Please send me an example gwt application which compiles to the single js file and it is compatible with nodejs.

Comment: My recollection (might be wrong, might be out of date) is that GWT code can only run in the browser.

Comment: @MichaelKay I also can create a single js file for browser. But when I started it in nodejs - I see an error message: use global instead of window.

Comment: Yes, I think GWT generates JS code that assumes the browser environment including a "window" object. It doesn't actually have to run in a browser, it just has to run in an environment that satisfies those dependencies. You may be able to create such an environment under node.js.

Answer (score 2):

GWT resulting code can be executed in any JS engine, it is just a java to js transpiler. But it is probably useless (or unnecessary complicated) to use GWT to run the transpiled code in the server-side.

If you are going to develop in JS, then you can create both the client and server sides in JS. Otherwise, if you have a Java server, you can use GWT to program the client-side in Java too. In both cases, the main goal is to share code in the same language but executed in different platforms, the browser (client-side) and the JVM (server-side).

If you still want to execute GWT code in node, you can get inspired by this library (outdated):
https://github.com/cretz/gwt-node

A modern solution will be to access node.js API using JsInterop and using SSO (Single Script).